# BATCH script doesn't work in Dockerfile build process

Tags: windows, docker, batch-file

I've a simple **BATCH** script script that perform a SHA256 checksum test.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

::Batch script to compare a file SHA256 checksum to a given one.
::Usage: checksum [FILE] [VALUE]

set filepath=%1
set checksum=%2
set idx=0

for /f %%F in ('certutil -hashfile %filepath% SHA256') do (
    set "out!idx!=%%F"
    set /a idx += 1
)
set filechecksum=%out1%

if /i %checksum%==%filechecksum% (
    echo %checksum% validated.
) else (
    echo Checksum validation falied.
    exit 1
)
```

I invoke it in a **Dockerfile** to validate itself:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909-amd64

COPY checksum.bat /
RUN /checksum.bat /checksum.bat 2b9dadc0b74dc25bd94552817b68c57df9c324ba28656c10ec787adf5611f3ec
```

This is the output I get:

```
$ docker image build -t gsscoder/test:v0_0 .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/3 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909-amd64
 ---> 9c2075893694
Step 2/3 : COPY checksum.bat /
 ---> 2224010db712
Step 3/3 : RUN /checksum.bat /checksum.bat 2b9dadc0b74dc25bd94552817b68c57df9c324ba28656c10ec787adf5611f3ec
 ---> Running in eb60dd5fe468
Checksum validation falied.
The command 'cmd /S /C /checksum.bat /checksum.bat 2b9dadc0b74dc25bd94552817b68c57df9c324ba28656c10ec787adf5611f3ec' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If I remove the `RUN` command and try it directly in the container or the host OS I've the exepcted correct result:

```
.\checksum.bat .\checksum.bat 2b9dadc0b74dc25bd94552817b68c57df9c324ba28656c10ec787adf5611f3ec

2b9dadc0b74dc25bd94552817b68c57df9c324ba28656c10ec787adf5611f3ec validated.
```

Why string comparison or something else fail during the build process?

I'm very curious to know.

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S.: I know I can do by other means (like using **PowerShell**), but I want know why in this way it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried copying the bat file to "." and then running it without prefixing it with "/"?

Comment: I suggest in your error message that you print the parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code fails, it's always a good idea to add some debug output.

Then you see that a `RUN /checksum.bat ...` results into a slightly different output.

`out1` isn't set, because `crtutil ... /checksum.bat` failed with

```
CertUtil: Unknown arg: /checksum.bat
```

All you have to change:

```
RUN /checksum.bat C:\checksum.bat 2b9dadc0b74dc25bd94552817b68c57df9c324ba28656c10ec787adf5611f3ec
```

Comment: yes you're right and it worked. Thank you! Can I ask what kind of debug `echo` have you added to spot the issue?

Comment: @gsscoder I added `echo "out!idx!=%%F"` into the loop